# JsonConverter: Return a single object or a List<Object> based on inbound JSON

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net

When my API sends back a single object, we'll call it Item (A GetEntity in OData terms), it looks like this:

```
{
  "d" : {
    "Item" : "123456",
    "OldItem" : "78921",
  }
}
```

When I grab a set of the same object, i.e. returning List of Item, I get:

```
{  
   "d":{  
      "results":[  
         {  
            "Item":"343431",
            "OldItem":"21314"
         },
         {  
            "Item":"341321",
            "OldItem":"43563"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Other than the obvious "d" base node I need to get rid of, I'm having trouble attempting to use the same class in C# to do this. I have an Item class as such:

```
public class Material : IEntity
    {
        [JsonProperty("Item")]
        public string material_number { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("OldItem")]
        public string old_material_number { get; set; }

        // Methods
        public Material() {}

        public bool Validate() { throw new NotImplementedException(); }
    }
```

I'd like to be able to call a custom `JsonConverter` to handle this, but I haven't been able to get some of the example out there for single object, array converters to work. Ideally, I should be able to call:

`JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` where `T` is either `Material` or `List<Material>`. How can I build a `JsonConverter` to handle both scenarios?

I'm calling the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>` as such:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(JObject.Parse(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result).SelectToken("d").ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                throw new Exception("Service Error");
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `JsonConverter` that should work for your situation.  Note that if there are any other JSON formats you could receive that are not shown in your question -- for example, if `d` can have a value of `null` when there are no results -- you may need to make adjustments to the converter.  Currently it will throw an exception if it encounters something it does not expect, but you could make it return null or an empty list instead, if you prefer.

```
public class MaterialArrayConverter : JsonConverter
{
    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JToken token = JToken.Load(reader);
        if (token.Type == JTokenType.Object)
        {
            JToken results = token["results"];
            if (results != null && results.Type == JTokenType.Array)
            {
                // we've got multiple items; deserialize to a list
                return results.ToObject<List<Material>>(serializer);
            }
            else if (results == null)
            {
                // "results" property not present; return a list of one item
                return new List<Material> { token.ToObject<Material>(serializer) };
            }
        }
        // some other format we're not expecting
        throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected JSON format encountered in MaterialArrayConverter: " + token.ToString());
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public override bool CanWrite
    {
        get { return false; }
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        // CanConvert is not called when [JsonConverter] attribute is used
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can use it by making a `RootObject` class annotated as shown below and then deserializing your JSON into that:

```
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty("d")]
    [JsonConverter(typeof(MaterialArrayConverter))]
    public List<Material> Materials { get; set; }
}
```

Then:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

From there you can retrieve the list of materials and use it as you see fit.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/tKb6Ke

Comment: It wouldn't be a list of one object. It would either be one material object, or a list of materials.

Comment: Right.  In the JSON is either a single material item or a list of material items.  But the converter makes it into a list in either case so you can handle it consistently.  Take a look at the fiddle to see what I mean.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to return your material(s) in a collection, you can use the following generic [`JsonConverter`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm)

```
public class SingleOrResultListConverter<T> : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(ICollection<T>).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }

    const string Results = "results";

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.Null)
            return null;
        if (objectType.IsArray)
        {
            var list = (List<T>)ReadJson(reader, typeof(List<T>), new List<T>(), serializer);
            return list.ToArray();
        }
        else
        {
            var list = (ICollection<T>)(existingValue ?? serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(objectType).DefaultCreator());
            if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartArray)
            {
                serializer.Populate(reader, list);
            }
            else if (reader.TokenType == JsonToken.StartObject)
            {
                JObject obj = null;
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    switch (reader.TokenType)
                    {
                        case JsonToken.PropertyName:
                            string propertyName = reader.Value.ToString();
                            if (!reader.Read())
                            {
                                throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected end while reading collection");
                            }
                            if (propertyName == Results)
                            {
                                serializer.Populate(reader, list);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                obj = obj ?? new JObject();
                                obj[propertyName] = JToken.Load(reader);
                            }
                            break;
                        case JsonToken.Comment:
                            break;
                        case JsonToken.EndObject:
                            if (obj != null)
                                list.Add(obj.ToObject<T>(serializer));
                            return list;
                    }
                }
                throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected end while reading collection");
            }
            else
            {
                throw new JsonSerializationException("Unexpected start token: " + reader.TokenType);
            }
            return list;
        }
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var collection = (ICollection<T>)value;
        if (collection.Count == 1)
        {
            serializer.Serialize(writer, collection.First());
        }
        else
        {
            writer.WriteStartObject();
            writer.WritePropertyName(Results);
            writer.WriteStartArray();
            foreach (var item in collection)
            {
                serializer.Serialize(writer, item);
            }
            writer.WriteEndArray();
            writer.WriteEndObject();
        }
    }
}
```

Then use it as follows:

```
var obj = JObject.Parse(json);
var subObj = obj["d"] ?? obj; // Strip the "d".

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = new[] { new SingleOrResultListConverter<Material>() } };

var list = subObj.ToObject<List<Material>>(JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings));
```

Or if you prefer an array to a `List<T>`:

```
var array = subObj.ToObject<Material[]>(JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings));
```

Prototype [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sGERMa).

**Update**

You need to make sure you are allocating and passing your converter to Json.NET.  Since your deserialization method is generic, you'll need to do something generic, like so:

```
var json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
var converters = typeof(T).GetCollectionItemTypes()
    .Select(t => (JsonConverter)Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(SingleOrResultListConverter<>).MakeGenericType(new [] { t })))
    .ToArray();
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { Converters = converters };
return JToken.Parse(json).SelectToken("d").ToObject<T>(JsonSerializer.CreateDefault(settings));
```

Using the extension method:

```
public static class TypeExtensions
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Return all interfaces implemented by the incoming type as well as the type itself if it is an interface.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="type"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetInterfacesAndSelf(this Type type)
    {
        if (type == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException();
        if (type.IsInterface)
            return new[] { type }.Concat(type.GetInterfaces());
        else
            return type.GetInterfaces();
    }

    public static IEnumerable<Type> GetCollectionItemTypes(this Type type)
    {
        foreach (Type intType in type.GetInterfacesAndSelf())
        {
            if (intType.IsGenericType
                && intType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ICollection<>))
            {
                yield return intType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The CanConvert function always returns false, thus I never hit the ReadJson. I've tried this approach using IList and others to no avail.

Comment: @jlrolin - Answer updated with [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/sGERMa).  can you show how you are calling `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>`?  On a second read of your question, I'm no longer sure what you want when you do `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Material>` for a single material but there are multiple results.  A `List<Material>` can hold one or more materials but a single `Material` cannot hold more than one.  And if there is only one result you don't need a converter at all.

Comment: @jlrolin - when you make the call, what is `T`?

Comment: It comes in as List<Material>

Comment: @jlrolin - answer updated.  You need to allocate and pass the converter, and since your method is generic, it needs to be allocated in a generic way.